# Django filter with two constraints on related model

Tags: django

I have a django app with models as follows:

- A `Question` model
- An `Answer` model, with a ForeignKey
  back to the Question. (A question can
  have multiple answers.)
- A `Flag` model, with a ForeignKey to
  the Answer. (An answer can be flagged
  as inappropriate.)

All of the above also have a `user` field, defining the user that created that object.

I'm trying to get a list of all Questions with answers from the current user which have been flagged. I tried this:

```
Question.objects.filter(answer__user=user).\
                 filter(answer__flag__isnull=False).distinct()
```

… but I believe that will return a list of Questions with answers from the current user and with answers which have been flagged, but will not necessarily guarantee that it is the user's answer that has been flagged.

Is there an easy way to do this? Basically, I want to make the `answer` part of the filter refer to the same answer on both of them.

Please let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query does exactly what you want, except that you should filter for questions where the flag is **not** `null`. Chained filters are `and`ed together, so it will filter out all questions that have an answer from the particular user and then filter that set for answers that are flagged.

You may also put those two criteria in the same `filter` call:

```
Question.objects.filter(answer__user=user, answer__flag__isnull=False)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The first filter will give me a set of all Questions with at least one Answer from that user. Then, the second filter will return questions matching that criteria that have a flagged answer. But if Question Q1 has Answers A1 and A2 from Users U1 and U2, respectively, and A2 is flagged, won't this query return Q1 for both U1 and U2?

And yes, you're absolutely right about isnull=False; I'll fix that.

Comment: Aha. It turns out that if I put them both in the same filter call, then it will do what I want. (See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships for more info.)

Comment: Just noting, as per the docs, this doesn't work the same for `.exclude()`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
questions = [a.question for a in user.answer_set.filter(flag__isnull=True)]
```

Edit: this does not return a queryset, of course. And to prevent duplicate questions, maybe wrap the list comprehension in a set().

Comment: I do, in fact, need it to be a queryset, because this may be passed off for further filtering later.